# Microsoft Graph API - how to retrieve tags (App Registrations)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In powershell, how can you use Microsoft Graph to get all the tags in an App Registration?

I tried googling but only saw tag data for teams.  My group has been trying to figure this one out with no luck.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: does this help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/tag?view=azure-cli-latest   I'm not sure what is tags in an App Registration. I didn't see `tag` blade in Azure AD.... Pls correct me if I misunderstood your problem.